# Why is DOM element border width not returned?

Tags: javascript, css, border

I've tried this in IE9 only, and I'm receiving just an empty string back - no border width.  What is wrong?!

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
<style type="text/css">
    .myCanvas {
        border-width: 2px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: red;
    }
</style>
</head><body>
    <div class="myCanvas">Something here</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function(){
            var borderWidth = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.borderWidth;
            console.log(borderWidth);
        })();
    </script>
</body>html>
```

Comment: What you're looking at is the style property set by the style attribute, what you need to look at is the computed style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `style` object only contains data stored in the element's HTML `style` attribute. Here the element has no `style` attribute, let alone a `border-width` declaration within. This would only work if your markup looked like this:

```
<div class="myCanvas" style="border-width:2px">Something here</div>
```

> 2px

To pull computed CSS styles, you need to use [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle):

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0],
    borderWidth = window.getComputedStyle(div).borderWidth;
console.log(borderWidth);
```

> 2px

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/32XTL/1).

Unfortunately this will not work on IE8, but will work on all other modern browsers. ([Browser Support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=getcomputedstyle))

Comment: And for IE 8 and older, if you need/decide to support them, you need something else.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela good point; added a Can I Use... link to the answer.

Comment: The answer is OK, but just to note, that there is no property borderWidth of getComputedStyle(), but all the others borderTopWidth, borderBottomWidth, etc...

Comment: @Hristo that depends on which browser you're using. Chrome includes a `borderWidth` property.

Answer (score 1):

`element.style` only refers to the element's style *attribute*. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style#Notes):

> To get the values of all CSS properties for an element you should use [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle) instead.